# XLL and VBA : Can't find DLL entry point Myfunc

Tags: c++, vba, dll, xll, xlw

I have a c++ library , and I am using xlw to create functions that can be used in Excel. So far, I was just releasing the xlw solution , and dropping the xll file on the excel sheet, and I could get my C++ functions. With VBA, I was using Application.run without any problems... 
Until I decided to use inputs by reference. Application.run does not seem to handle that. Therefore , I tried to declare the function in VBA :

```
Declare Function myFunction Lib "C:\temp\XLL_Project\Release\Template.xll"
(ByRef outV1 As Double, ByRef outV2 As Double, ByRef outV3 As Double)
```

but I got the error Message : Can't find DLL entry point myFunction in 
C:\temp\XLL_Project\Release\Template.xll

Though I could use Template.xll functions in Excel.

As for the xll generator, I use the default library provided by Xlw and I just modified the cppinterface.h file as well as the source.cpp file for the implementation

cppinterface.h
:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H


#include "xlw/MyContainers.h"
#include <xlw/CellMatrix.h>
#include <xlw/DoubleOrNothing.h>
#include <xlw/ArgList.h>

 using namespace xlw;

 //<xlw:libraryname=MyTestLibrary



double myFunction(
double & outV1, double &outV2, double & outV3);
```

Thanks